# sql - for each actor, which movie of actor was rented most and how many times it was rented

Tags: mysql, sql

In [Sakila](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/sakila/en/sakila-installation.html) sample database, how to get most rented movie per actor and its count?
In other words, how to get top/most occurrence of relationship with its count?

I was able to group results by actor and movie, but I couldn't limit the results per actor:

```
select concat(a.first_name, ' ', a.last_name ) as Actor, f.title as Movie, count(f.film_id) as Count
    from actor as a
        left join film_actor fa on a.actor_id = fa.actor_id
        inner join film f on fa.film_id = f.film_id
        left join inventory i on f.film_id = i.film_id
        left join rental r on i.inventory_id = r.inventory_id
    group by a.actor_id, f.film_id
    order by a.actor_id, Count desc
```

phpMyAdmin has demo with Sakila [here](https://demo.phpmyadmin.net/master-config/db_sql.php?db=sakila)

Desired result would be:

```
    Actor                 Movie         Rent Count
NICK WAHLBERG       GOODFELLAS SALUTE   31
ED CHASE            FROST HEAD          30
PENELOPE GUINESS    GLEAMING JAWBREAKER 29
```

Comment: Could you edit the question add your desired result or more clarify the question.

Comment: @YogeshSharma I added a desired result. More clarified question is in the title.

Comment: Just put your current query in subquery form and group by them  with actor name and use max(Movie) , max(count) to get topmost counts by each actors with their movies.

Comment: @YogeshSharma it will not retrieve movies that were rented the same number of times (the `max(movie)` will return only the first movie in alphabetical order). Don't know if this is a requirement though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [CTE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html), then select all rows that match the maximum count (using the [ANY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/any-in-some-subqueries.html) predicate) :

```
with q1 as (
    select
        concat(a.first_name, ' ', a.last_name ) as Actor,
        f.title as Movie,
        count(f.film_id) as Count
    from
        actor as a
        left join film_actor fa on a.actor_id = fa.actor_id
        inner join film f on fa.film_id = f.film_id
        left join inventory i on f.film_id = i.film_id
        left join rental r on i.inventory_id = r.inventory_id
    group by
        a.actor_id,
        f.film_id
)
select * from q1
where (q1.Actor, q1.Count) = any(select q2.Actor, max(q2.Count) from q1 q2 group by q2.Actor)
order by q1.Actor
```

You can also use a correlated subquery instead of `ANY`, so the where clause would be :

```
where q1.Count = (select max(q2.Count) from q1 q2 where q1.Actor = q2.Actor)
```

Comment: Can this be done without CTE because looks like CTE in MySql was not supported until version 8.0?

Comment: CTE is simply a form of "code re-use". You can replace it by a subquery (replace occurrences of `q1` with the CTE query). Depending on your need you would also consider using a temp table or a view.